# Ubuntu 12.04 not showing in boot selection after installing from Wubi in Windows 7

Tags: grub2, dual-boot, windows-7

I know there are already several instances of this problem but I just don't find a similar issue as mine so pardon for being redundant.I am new to Ubuntu but I very much like to understand the whole thing about it.

I installed Ubuntu 12.04 from WUBI on my Existing Windows 7 OS. I have 2 partitions C: and D:
What I did was select D: as where the Ubuntu be installed and give it free space. The installation went fine then then I rebooted my machine. Surprisingly it did not go to the boot selection screen, It just went straight to Windows 7.

What I did is to install EasyBCD and found out that there is no entry for Ubuntu in the Bootloader only for Windows 7.

I am not really quite familiar in using one of these. I can start with whatever everyone will post here for answer and I will gladly try them.

Answer (score 1):

So I just decided to uninstall Wubi from D:\ and just download the ISO 32bit and create a bootable USB disk by following the steps from [How to create a bootable USB stick in Windows.](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows)

I just tested it and worked fine. The only thing I noticed is that my network doesn't work (wired and wireless) I was thinking that probably it's only a live OS that was preloaded and the config are not set yet but it's my theory. I'll just probably try and install the ISO package and test everything from it.